# Inserting dat by using for?

Tags: import, data

I have data set in a form ROG1.dat, ROG2.dat,...,ROG100.dat, I want to import all of them in Mathematica, Can you tell me how?
Best

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
SetDirectory["path to the directory with the data set"];

fileNames = "ROG" <> ToString@# <> ".dat" & /@ Range[100];

data = Import[#, "Data"] & /@ fileNames;
```

If in the folder there are just .dat files that you want to import, you can also use (edited after comment below):

```
data = AssociationMap[Import[#, "Data"] &, FileNames["*.dat"]]
```

Comment: `FileNames` accepts glob operators for filenames, e.g. `FileNames["*.dat"]`, so `Select` is superfluous. Also, using `FileNames` like that will cause them to be listed in lexicographical order, e.g. `In[90]:= FileNames["*.dat"] (*Out[90]= {"ROG10.dat", "ROG1.dat", "ROG20.dat", "ROG2.dat"}*) `. If you're running at least v10, I'd suggest using `AssociationMap` instead of `Map`, then you can re-order at will.

Comment: Thanks for that! I fixed the FileNames[] command in my post according to your suggestion :)

Comment: You're welcome. You already have my +1. :)